# How do i put spacing for ym matrix?

Tags: c, visual-studio

How do I make my matrix nicely spaced out?

[image]

This is my code for generating the matrix:

```
void print_graph(void)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            printf("%.1d", G[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Da9K.png)

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could indent each line with some tabs:

```
printf("\t");
for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
...
```

For adding a space between all values you have two options: add a space after the value:

```
printf("%.1d ", G[i][j]);
```

or use the width

```
printf("% 2d", G[i][j]);
```

See also: [format specs](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/format_specs.html)